# Does Kendo ui have breadcrumb navigation menu

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

breadcrumb navigation menu just like A>B>C，Does anybody know kendo ui have that widget?

Comment: Did you try http://www.telerik.com/forums/breadcrumbs-to-selected-node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with this solution.Please note that Kendo classes are not imported in this example so it wont show the correct result. Please import kendo css classes to get the correct results as shown below in the screenshot.
[image]

```js
$("#tree").kendoTreeView({
    select: function(e) {
        var breadcrumb = [];
        var treeView = this;

        $(e.node)
            .parents("li")
            .andSelf()
            .each(function() {
                var nodeText = $.trim(treeView.text(this));
                breadcrumb.push(nodeText);
            });

        breadcrumb = breadcrumb.join(" > ");

        $("#breadcrumb").text(breadcrumb);
        
    }
    
});
```

```css
.k-bot{
    float:left;

}
.k-item{
 margin:20px;
}
.k-icon{
margin-left:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Breadcrumb Trail: <span id="breadcrumb">Root</span>

<ul id="tree">
    <li>Root
        <ul>
            <li>Parent 1
                <ul>
                    <li>Child 1</li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Follows the example of Breadcrumb for KendoMenu:

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
select: function(e) {
    var breadcrumb = [];
    var treeView = this;

    $(e.item)
        .parents("li")
        .andSelf()
        .each(function() {
            var nodeText = $.trim($(this).find('span:first').text());
            breadcrumb.push(nodeText);
        });

    breadcrumb = breadcrumb.join(" > ");

    $("#breadcrumb").text(breadcrumb);                        
}
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fogatt/b6e4mqL3/3/)